# Tree structure for muticolored region quadtree

Tags: datastructure, quadtree

Is a B+ tree suitable for a multicolored region quadtree (for example, one segmenting a plot of land into several crops)?

I recently purchased a copy of Samet's 'Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Data Structures,' which, while containing a vast amount of insight, is often anecdotal. What I've read through has not specifically stated that the B+ tree can only be used for binary images, but that has been the case of each of his examples.

If this structure is not a viable option, what would be a good alternative(s) to start reading up on?

I'm less intersted in spatial efficiency and more concerned with update/retrieval speed and neighbor finding, if not implicit to the structure.

If you have multiple suggestions, can you do a brief compare/contrast?